# Random texture transformation for each side of a cube

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I'm trying to make a stone cube like in Minecraft.
Each side has the same 16x16 texture, but it is randomly rotated(0°/180°) and flipped (4 different looks: [image: 1]) depending on the cube location in the world.

The cubes in my scene are 1x1x1 m.

I don't know ow to do this in Blender.

Comment: Have you explored the uv editor ? You can rotate and scale individual UV sets there

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, but I would have to do it manually for each cube. I'm thinking of using a 3d noise texture and object position in nodes. I just need to know how to get the transformation information from the noise, I used mapping node for plank texture, so I already have the inputs.

Comment: You could use a set of cubes which share the same mesh but have different materials assigned

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the cubes in Eevee you need six materials to get a completely random texture for each face of the cube.

In Cycles you can get away with only one material because it supports the *Geometry* node's *[Random Per Island](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html)* value. To get this to work you additionally need to separate all faces of the cube. This can be done by an *Edge Split* modifier and *Mark Sharp* for all edges.

**How to randomize textures for each face of the cube (Eevee + Cycles)**

You only need one image texture that fits the face of the cube. It will be flipped (x/y) to create the other three variations. A rotation of 180° can be done by two flips (x-axis and y-axis).

Texture used in the example → [image: cube texture]

Having said this, now UV unwrap each face of the cube separately so that it becomes a UV island and covers the whole image. Select one face, <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrap*. Select next face, <kbd>U</kbd> *Unwrap*, ... and so on. Then you have 6 UV islands stacked on top of each other:

[image: uv unwrap]<sup>UV unwrap</sup>

Now create a material setup that transforms the texture. It uses a choosen unique value and the random value of the object to randomly flip the texture on the x or y axis, or both. A flip is basically a scale by -1.

Make five copies of the material and assign a different material to each face of the cube (*Material.001, ..., Material.006*). Give each material a unique seed. This is just a random value. You can choose what you want. It's `1.111` for Material.001 in the example.

[image: node setup for texture randomization]<sup>1000 little random texured cubes</sup>

With the material's seed and the object's random value, you can get a random value for each face of every cube thanks to the *White Noise Texture* (2D) node that uses both values (x and y) of the created vector as seed. The *Math* node (Greater Than) decides if the texture is flipped or not (0 or 1). The next *Math* node (Multiply Add) calculates the needed scale value (-1 or 1). The result is used to flip the texture on the x-axis - or leave it alone.

The same is done for the y-axis with a second random value that is provided by the other *White Noise Texture* (1D) node. The seed (W) for this node is the random value of the first *White Noise Texture* node to get another different random value.

Both calculated random scale values are combined to a vector and used for the *Mapping* node that finally does the transformation of the image texture. That's it.

Comment: Thanks! It helped